# Canvas fill text

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How to fill text on the canvas of TImage of a second form from the button click on the main form? 
I have tried it several times but the canvas remain blank.

My attempt:

```
Form2.Image1.Canvas.BeginScene;
Form2.Image1.Canvas.Font.Size:=18;
Form2.Image1.Canvas.Font.Family:='Arial';
Form2.Image1.Canvas.Fill.Color:=claBlack;
Form2.Image1.Canvas.Font.Style:=[TFontStyle.fsbold];
Form2.Image1.Canvas.FillText(TRectF.Create(4,70,70,200),'Hello',true,1,[TFillTex‌​tFlag.RightToLeft], TTextAlign.Leading, TTextAlign.Leading);
Form2.Image1.Canvas.EndScene;
```

Comment: You might show what you have tried :-)

Comment: You can edit your question and include the essential source code. Then it will be easy to see what you have done wrong.

Comment: If you've "tried several times", you should have at least one try you can add to your question. You can [edit] it now to do so. :-)

Comment: Form2.Image1.Canvas.BeginScene;
Form2.Image1.Canvas.Font.Size:=18;
Form2.Image1.Canvas.Font.Family:='Arial';
Form2.Image1.Canvas.Fill.Color:=claBlack;
Form2.Image1.Canvas.Font.Style:=[TFontStyle.fsbold];
Form2.Image1.Canvas.FillText(TRectF.Create(4,70,70,200),'Hello',true,1,[TFillTextFlag.RightToLeft], TTextAlign.Leading, TTextAlign.Leading);

Form2.Image1.Canvas.EndScene;

Comment: This is the source code on the button click  procedure

Comment: Have you checked the Font.Color property? Could it be a case of black on black?

Comment: Yes I have checked the Font.Color property but nothing changes.

Comment: -1 Your code works here. Please show a complete program that demonstrates the fault, and be precise about which version of Delphi you use.

Answer (score 2):

Using TImage with firemonkey, you will have to create or load a bitmap before will be able to paint.

```
Form2.Image1.Bitmap.Create(Round(Form2.Image1.width),Round(Form2.Image1.height));
With  Form2.Image1.Bitmap.Canvas do
  begin
    BeginScene;
    Font.Size:=18;
    Font.Family:='Arial';
    Fill.Color:=TAlphaColors.Black;
    Font.Style:=[TFontStyle.fsbold];
    FillText(TRectF.Create(4,70,70,200),'Hello',true,1,[TFillTextFlag.ftRightToLeft], TTextAlign.taLeading,TTextAlign.taCenter);
    EndScene;
  end;
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can't judge, since I'm on XE3, maybe a change in later versions.

Comment: Yeah, I tried on XE7. FMX questions are hard (!) to answer without a version.

Comment: @bummi - I'm not sure you should encourage the usage of `with` if it can be avoided (anytime). Also please note that this is my opinion so feel free to ignore it.

Comment: @mg30rg I agree in general, I just tried to keep it a short and readable, but you are right `WITH` should be avoided.